# Compare dates in row and remove conflicts

Tags: r, date, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with an id, and three date columns which should be the same in each row but there are sometimes conflicts.

For each row I want to compare the three dates, and if at least two agree then put that date, but if all disagree then put NA.

It is slightly complicated by the fact that there are also NAs for unknown dates. If there are two NA's and one date I am happy to keep that single date.

I could do this with a bunch of ifelse's but was wondering if there was a neat way of doing this.

An example of problem is this dataframe:

```
dataDF <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  date1 = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2000-05-01', NA,            NA,          '2000-01-05', NA)),
  date2 = as.Date(c('2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-06', NA)),
  date3 = as.Date(c(NA,           '2000-01-02', '2000-05-03',  NA         , '2000-01-07', NA))
```

)

I would want to end up with a new clean `date` column such that the dataframe looks  like the following:

```
  id      date1      date2      date3       date
1  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01       <NA> 2000-01-01
2  2 2000-05-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-02 2000-01-02
3  3       <NA> 2000-01-03 2000-05-03       <NA>
4  4       <NA> 2000-01-04       <NA> 2000-01-04
5  5 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-07       <NA>
6  6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

**Explanation:** 
This function works like this: 
1. For every row, if all values are NA, it returns NA 
2. For every row, if all values are unique, it returns NA. 
3. If there are 2 NAs in a row, it returns the non-NA value. 
4. Else, it returns one of the value which occur twice.

```
# helper function
get_values <- function(x)
{
    if (all(is.na(x)) | length(unique(x)) == 3) return (NA)
    else if ((length(unique(x)) == 1) & (! any(is.na(x)))) return (unique(x))
    else if (sum(is.na(x)) == 2) return (x[!is.na(x)])
    else return(as.character(x[duplicated(x)]))

}


# apply function row wise
dataDF$date <- apply(dataDF[,-1], 1, get_values)

  id      date1      date2      date3       date
1  1 2000-01-01 2000-01-01       <NA> 2000-01-01
2  2 2000-05-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-02 2000-01-02
3  3       <NA> 2000-01-03 2000-05-03       <NA>
4  4       <NA> 2000-01-04       <NA> 2000-01-04
5  5 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-07       <NA>
6  6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesnt quite work, if I have 3 values all of the same then it returns it in the clean column twice. It is close enough though so will have a play around and hopefully get it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've added another case in the function. Now it returns the unique value when all three dates are same.